# google-cloud-storage: Obtaining ClientID and Client_Secret_Key by HTTP requests

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am developing a service which is suppose to browse all project `IDs/buckets/objects` for a particular google user.

I have created the projects using Google Console and able to get the `device/user/verification-url` etc..and able to get the access

and refersh tokens as well.

While I got these, I had to use the `ClientID` and `Client_Secret_Key` (which as a google user) I got to see in Google Console.

Ideally, I would like to obtain this information(ClientID and secret type) in backend by using some HTTP requests or may be by some 
other means.

Is anybody aware of how to obtain these ?

Comment: You can use the [oauth web flow](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth)

Comment: Actually this link is for obtaining the ClientID/Client_secret_type using Google Console. I am developing the application in a device where browser application is not present so  I need to do this in backend. Any suggestion !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements - why do you need to make a service call to obtain the client ID and secret? You would still have to log in through some other means before you could get any form of credentials, so ultimately you'll have have to pass the client ID and secret to your service somehow (e.g., by giving your application access to a private key file).

It sounds like your use case is exactly what [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) are meant to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the concept of a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts)?

A service account is like S3's Access Key ID and Secret Key -- rather than being a particular Google user's data, it's the application's data.